# Why doesn't Chrome seem to like OS-specific mods?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, ultramon

I was a Firefox guy for a long time. Recently I switched to Chrome for its minimalism and (frankly) because I like Google. Everything has been going great, except for one small (yet annoying) issue.

On my PC, I installed UltraMon, a program that offers better-than-stock multi-monitor management tools. One of my favorite features of UltraMon is a little button it puts up by my titlebar buttons that causes the window to switch monitors. This button shows up in all of my apps except for Google Chrome.

Now, today, on my Mac, I just installed KeyRemap4MacBook so that I could "fix" my Home and End keys (hey, I'm primarily a Windows guy, cut me a break), remapping them to Command A, and Command E respectively. The remapping works great in all of my applications except for Google Chrome. Chrome appears to ignore them.

Obviously I'm open to any fixes you guys might have for this, but, at the very least, what's up with Google Chrome? Why doesn't it like these changes? If this keeps up, I might go back to Firefox... Aside from the bi-weekly updates, it wasn't too bad...

Comment: might be a app specific I issue, I use Actual Multiple Monitors & it's buttons shows up. Auto HotKey works fine as well.

Comment: Maybe UltraMon does not support chrome...

Comment: huh. Well. I guess We'll leave it at that then...That's disappointing. Oh well. Thanks for the info guys.